# Dummy data generator

Tags: test-data

Can you suggest sites where I can generate dummy data based on my requirement for testing purposes of my project?

Note: I need a dummy data for usage of VMs and physical servers in terms of memory, CPU, disk, I/O utilization in percentage. Is there any site which provides utility to generate this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [InfoChimps](http://infochimps.org/), they may have the sort of data your are after. But if you're just looking for numbers, it should be exceptionally trivial to just generate them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try http://www.generatedata.com/#generator

Answer (score 0):

Obviously late to the discussion but in case anyone finds their way here.  [The baseball database](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/) contains some moderately large datasets (160,000+ records in the Fielding table, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [MySQL Datagenerator](http://paulthedutchman.nl/datagenerator). Perhaps that is what you are looking for...